# Simple commercially free alarm clock for Windows

Tags: windows, open-source, alarm-clock

I need a simple alarm clock for Windows 10 which should be free for commercial use.

I searched on alternativeto.net and the first choice was [free alarm clock](https://alternativeto.net/software/free-alarm-clock)
But it did not work at work for some reason that I cannot figure out.

The next choice was "Digital Clock 4" but it is not maintained anymore.

What should be the alternative to this?

Answer (score 1):

### [WatchTheClock](https://sourceforge.net/projects/watchtheclock/)

Portable stopwatch, countdown timer and alarm clock for Windows

- Portable
- Very small (only 600 KB) and resource-efficient
- Modern and simple UI
- Stopwatch function
- Countdown function
- Alarm function
- Buttons in taskbar
- Countdown notification with sound or without

Comment: does this answer work for you?